# SCSS Mixin Executes Inside Of Incorrect Selector In Angular Application

Tags: css, angular, variables, sass, scss-mixins

I am running an angular16 project that uses SCSS for styles. The project uses Angular Material for its theming, and I am trying to set global variables in my styles.scss dynamically by switching the class on my root  tag.

For example, something like this:

```
$primary: white !default;

@mixin set-theme($color){
    $primary: $color !global;
}

html.light{
   @include set-theme(blue)
}

html.dark{
   @include set-theme(purple)
}
```

My index.html would look something like this:

```
<html lang="en" class="light">
...
</html>
```

But my `$primary` variable would have a value of purple. Why is the second `@include` executing when my `html` tag does not have the `.dark` class?

---

My setup is similar to the code above, and I expected this...

```
html.dark{
   @include set-theme(purple)
}
```

to not execute since the class is not active.